# Lightning Experience Rollout

Tags: lightning, trailhead

I edited the page to

```
<apex:page ...>
    <apex:slds />
    <div class="slds-scope">
        <table class="slds-table slds-table_bordered slds-table_cell-buffer">
            ....
        </table>
    </div>
</apex:page>
```

and added  to the page as well, but I am getting this error when I Check Challenge:

```
Challenge Not yet complete... here's what's wrong: 
The AccountTab Visualforce page does not include one or both of the 
following: the apex:slds tag in the page, or the slds-table value in 
the table.
```

I've also tried to load the old pageBlockTable with Salesforce Classic and the new Lightning Table in Lightning, but still getting the same error.

Has anyone been able to run into this problem and solve it?

Comment: you don't need to change the existing structure. Just add styleClass with slds class  to the pageBlockTable  tag, so as to get it done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ysr Shk is correct. I was able to get through this one by adding `styleClass="slds-table"` to the `pageBlockTable` tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
<apex:page standardStylesheets="false" standardController="Account" recordSetVar="accounts" tabStyle="account">
<apex:slds />
<div class="slds-scope">
    <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!accounts}" var="a" styleClass="slds-table">
            <apex:column headerValue="{!$ObjectType.Account.Fields.Name.Label}">
                <apex:outputLink value="{!URLFOR($Action.Account.View, a.id)}">{!a.name}</apex:outputLink>
            </apex:column>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</div>
```